# LocalDate - How to remove character 'T' in LocalDate

Tags: java, eclipse, date, java-8

How to remove T in my localDate?

I need to remove the 'T' to match data in my database.

This is my code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

String strLocalDate = patientDiagnosisByDoctor.getDiagnosisDateTime().toLocalDateTime().toString();

LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(strLocalDate, formatter);

System.out.println(localDate);
```

I got this output:

```
2015-10-23T03:34:40
```

What is the best way to remove the 'T' character? Any idea guys?

Comment: Use a `DateTimeFormat`

Comment: "to match data in my database"? Are your dates stored as `VARCHAR`????

Comment: @Andreas I'm using datetime in MySQL

Comment: Well, then, unless you're building the SQL by string concatenation and leave yourself vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), the database will never see or return a value with a `T` in it, because you're sending/receiving `Timestamp` values in the JDBC calls, so your question is meaningless.

Comment: @Andreas exactly sir, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> What is the best way to remove the 'T' character? Any idea guys?

Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the value of `LocalDateTime` the way you want it...

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

String strLocalDate = "2015-10-23T03:34:40";

LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(strLocalDate, formatter);

System.out.println(localDate);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(localDate));
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss yyyy-MM-dd ").format(localDate));
```

Which prints...

```
2015-10-23T03:34:40
2015-10-23 03:34:40
03:34:40 2015-10-23
```

Remember, date/time objects are just a container for amount of time which has passed since a fixed point in time (like the Unix epoch), they don't have a internal/configurable format of their own, they tend to use the current locale's format.

Instead, when you want to present the date/time value, you should first use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the date/time value to what ever format you want and display that

> I need to remove the 'T' to match data in my database.

Opps, missed that part.

In this case, you should be converting your Date/Time values to use `java.sql.Timestamp` and using a `PreparedStatement` to insert/update them

Comment: Any idea on how to remove trailing '.0' ?

2015-10-23 03:34:40.0 <---

Comment: `substring()`, but where are you getting that value? Nothing shown so far would do that.

Comment: from sql.timestamp, nevermind, MySQL does not detect that. Thank you sir

Comment: FYI: you'd normally change the format, but in your case, you don't need it, you jays need to use Timestamp and let the database worry about it

Comment: @Andreas Why not just change the format specifier, mind you, for inserting values in the database, you just need to use Timestamp and let the database worry about :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Preaching to the choir, man. Never use string concatenation to build SQL, always use `PreparedStatement`. No formatting issues, and no SQL Injection vulnerabilities. That's why my comment "answer" was shortened to one word. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
    String localTime = "2018-09-13 00:00:00";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(localTime, formatter);
    String replace = date.toString().replace("T", " ");
    System.out.println(replace);
```

***2018-09-13 00:00***

Answer (score 3):

Simple option using the *Joda-Time* library.

```
new LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London")).toString().replace("T", " ");
```