# Parse date to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format

Tags: java, database, datetime, spring-jdbc

I wanted to parse a date using LocalDateTime.parse() method with the date format  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, but what I actually get is a date of format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss. I don't need that 'T'. Please see below the code

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2016-10-31 23:59:59", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

The result I am getting is 2016-10-31T23:59:59. See that 'T'. The 'T' is causing issues so that I am unable to persist it to my database. I try to persist the value in a column of type `datetime`; I am getting the error - `org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar`.

See the values which are working

```
VALUES('US','101','test','firstname','middleName','preferedN‌​ame','lastName',
       '198‌​9-01-01','M',1,'1122‌​1123','test@test.com‌​','address1','addres‌​s2','Bloomingdale','‌​IL','US','689850',
       1,‌​1,'11111','2016-12-3‌​1 23:59:59')
```

(no `T` in last value)

which is not working:

```
VALUES('US','101','test','firstname','middleName','preferedN‌​ame','lastName',
       '198‌​9-01-01','M',1,'1122‌​1123','test@test.com‌​','address1','addres‌​s2','Bloomingdale','‌​IL','US','689850',
       1,‌​1,'11111','2016-12-3‌​1T23:59:59')
```

(with the `T` in the last value).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What you see is the internal representation of the Date. Because a `Date` has no format

Comment: 2016-10-31T23:59:59 - The 'T' is causing issues so that I am unable to persist it to my database.

Comment: What is the type of the column, How do you try to store the date, what is the error message?

Comment: from the javadoc of `LocalDateTime`, as `parse` returns one: 

`A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30. `, you´re not really formatting, you´re just seeing what `LocalDateTime#toString` does print, where the code simply does `return date.toString() + 'T' + time.toString()`. There´s your `T`, it´s not bound to any Format and is just a literal beeing printed there.

Comment: Date/Time objects **DO NOT** have a concept of formatting, they are containers for the number of milliseconds from a given point in time.  This is why there a date/time formatters - I'd recommend having a look at [Parsing and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) trail

Comment: type of the colume is datetime , I am getting the error - org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Comment: So Show the relevant code. It has nothing todo with the date

Comment: See the values which are working  VALUES('US','101','test','firstname','middleName','preferedName','lastName','1989-01-01','M',1,'11221123','test@test.com','address1','address2','Bloomingdale','IL','US','689850',1,1,'11111',**'2016-12-31 23:59:59'**)

Comment: which is not working VALUES('US','101','test','firstname','middleName','preferedName','lastName','1989-01-01','M',1,'11221123','test@test.com','address1','address2','Bloomingdale','IL','US','689850',1,1,'11111',**'2016-12-31T23:59:59'**)

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` and a `java.sql.Timestamp` and let the database sort it out

Comment: @ajithgeorge as mentioned before, you wont get rid of the `T` with your current implementation (well you didn´t provide it), as you probably just print out the `LocalDateTime#toString` inside your SQL statment. The `T` here is a fix literal in `LocalDateTime#toString` which you wont get rid of. Instead you might want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8) on how to properly format or use MadProgrammer's hint.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337487/localdate-how-to-remove-character-t-in-localdate

Comment: What’s the point in parsing your date if what you care about is the string that you had from the beginning (with no `T` in it)?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and add the information about the values that work and those that don’t work when inserting into your database.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I’ve read that new JDBC drivers accept `java.time` class instances so you need not use the oldfashioned `java.sql.Timestamp`. If you aren’t lucky to have a new enough driver, converting from `Instant` to `Timestamp` is as easy as `Timestamp.fromInstant()`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Been a LONG time since I had to interact with jdbc and all my interactions with the new date/time API is what I do in my personal time - having said, parsing the value to String is the wrong approach 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LocalDateTime is not stored as string, but as object.

You are getting a **"T"** because the .toString() method return the ISO format by default, as stated in:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

> **toString**
>
> public String toString()
>
> Outputs this date-time as a String, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.
>
> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm 
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS 
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS  
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The Format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the
>   time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

To output as you need use **format** function.

```java
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-10-31 23:59:59", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

System.out.println("toString: " + d.toString());
//toString: 2016-10-31T23:59:59                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
System.out.println("format:   " + d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
//format:   2016-10-31 23:59:59
```